# c# singleton inheriting from non-singleton for integration testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton

I have a timer in my class that is I only ever want one of so I have a static reference to it in my Main. During integration tests (not in normal runtime) it gets instantiated multiple times through different tests.

My idea was to create a Singleton that inherits all the functionality to ensure there is only ever one. I was wandering if this is sensible or will I come across some pitfalls I haven't thought of yet?

e.g In my Integration Test I am currently using

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTimerTest()
{
    MyTimer t = new Mytimer();
    t.Start();
}
```

whereas after this change I would use

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTimerTest()
{
    //creates a new instance or retrieves an already existing one
    MytimerSingleton.Instance.Start();

}
```

thus avoiding the chance I might have two running - (as they access a single resource in the file system)

**Update:** Corrected terminology from unit testing to integration testing.

Comment: inherits, or encapsulates? :)

Comment: Will you use the base class in your unit tests and your derived singleton class in your main app?

Comment: @magnus pong I was going to inherit but it could encapsulate as easily. The base class I use in my code and the inherited class I was going to use in my unit tests.

Comment: What does the inherited class add to the base class?

Comment: just the singleton pattern - I'll edit the question to explain more :)

Comment: What do you need a timer for? My unit test runner tells me how long a test took.

Comment: Are there any side effects of the timer running when not being tested (since it never gets cleaned up, even after the related tests are complete)?  Is Mytimer ever created anywhere else (it sounds like the answer is no)?

Comment: @David Kemp - It's nothing to do with the unit tests - it simply polls some resources and does a few other things.

Comment: @Richard: So this is more of an Integration Test than a Unit test?

Comment: @David Kemp yes you're right, it's more of an integration test.

Comment: @forsvarir no there are no side effects if it's running while not being tested. There are only problems is multiple instances are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I would say thats a bad idea (tm).

A unit test needs to test a single unit of functionality. Really there should only ever be one class instantiated in any one test.

By making your Timer class a singleton, I get the feeling you will be testing a class that just happens to be using your Timer. This test will then be testing two classes. Don't do it!

Instead :

When testing the class that uses your Timer, you should create a mock of your Timer class and pass that in to your class under test. Then if you break your Timer class, the Timer class tests fail, but all the other classes will still pass. Debugging is a piece of cake as you will instantly know it is your Timer class that is broken.

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty bad idea, because it links your unit tests together, so they aren't independent any more. This can lead to side effects with some tests failing only, when executed together with other tests or the other way around. Avoid it if possible. The same is true for static classes and members.

**Update:**
Now that you clarified your question, let me say this:

1. Your unit tests should be self contained, that means, you shouldn't access the file system, as this again introduces the possibility of side effects between your tests.
2. You can introduce a `TearDown` method that is called after each test. In this method you could ensure that the timer is cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The reason I was doing it was so that if one of my unit tests failed to Dispose the time properly then it would still not effect the rest of the run.

Comment: yes I agree on all these principles but I have over 500 tests. Around 200 of them are clearly unit tests and follow these principles. The others are more Integration tests crossing many modules and some starting different processes or threads to simulate user behaviour. I've tried to keep it as clean and decoupled as possible but I'm still finding multiple instances of the timer so was wandering if this is a suitable method to prevent imperfect coding from ruining my test runs.

Comment: @Richard: You should change your question then and indicate that it is an integration test and you know, that it is one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you reorganize your testing? In essence if you create a singleton there really can only be one so if your tests require multiple timers then you should reorganize them to work with an already present and active timer.

Comment: @mmx no my tests don't require multiple timers, but there are multiple tests that use the timer so I was finding that if one of them failed to clean up, I would end up with two timer instances.

Answer (score 1):

Who gets to stop the timer? If there's only one, then *any* call to Stop() will stop the timer.

You might be better off using a **Fixture** (like `IUseFixture<>` in XUnit.Net) to handle this.

Comment: Hi David, once started the timer will not stop until the program is exited. I don't mind if multiple starts are called - the can be triggered by a variety of user inputs, I simply don't want to end up with two instances running in this case.